# NPE in Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

We've received multiple crash reports for our application in Google Play with the same stack trace which we are unable to reproduce on our phones. App has crashed on LG G5 as well as on another Chinese phone.

Here's the stack trace we're receiving:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cl.i(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:44)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:122)
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$6.zzb(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onStart(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2210)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1337)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2837)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2216)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1337)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5996)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2670)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18925)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2157)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1261)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6239)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

We're using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1` as a dependency in our Gradle file. I read there were some issues with some phones with SD card issues and the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but we can't really reproduce the crash on our side to tell if the problem is in that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: problem with write sd card storage to write the some needed data even not bind the map related data thats why issue is generated.